# Why is info@example valid according to HTML5 <input type="email">?

Tags: html, validation, input

why does an e-mail address like: `info@example` (without a .TLD) validate in `<input type="email">` as a correct e-mail address?

I've tried:

- `info@` = invalid e-mail, as expected
- `info@example` = valid, NOT as expected
- `info@example.com` = valid, as expected

Ofcourse, I can validate form input using regular expressions or other methods, but the question remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 supports email addresses without domain extension because it is perfectly valid for local email addresses in mail server. So, to support every usecases, HTML5 does support it.
But, ICANN highly discourages dotless email addresses therefore you shouldn't solely rely on HTML5 email validation rather compliment it with another regex validation.